# how can i Convert JSON structure?

Tags: json

This is what I have now... I have to transform the structure to meet my needs...

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "Latitude": 1.29997, 
            "Longitude": 103.8225
        }, 

        {
            "Latitude": 1.30786, 
            "Longitude": 103.75999
        }
    ]
}
```

this is what I need....

```
{                                                                         
"features": [
    { "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 103.83697, 1.33502 ] } },
    { "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 103.8586, 1.31584 ] } },
    { "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 103.86744, 1.35397 ] } }
]
}
```

Comment: Which language are you using to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you can do that using the [`map` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) :

```
var obj = {
  'value': [
    ...
  ]
};

var newObj = {}
newObj.features = obj.value.map(function (elt) {
  return {
    'geometry': {
      'type': 'Point',
      'coordinates': [
        elt.Latitude,
        elt.Longitude
      ]
    }
  }
})

console.log(newObj)
```